# Using sinon and mocha to test node.js http.get

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, sinon

Let's say I have the following function

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');

var getLikes = function(graphId, callback) {
    // request to get the # of likes
    var req = http.get('http://graph.facebook.com/' + graphId, function(response) {
        var str = '';
        // while data is incoming, concatenate it
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });
        // data is fully recieved, and now parsable
        response.on('end', function () {
            var likes = JSON.parse(str).likes;
            var data = {
                _id: 'likes',
                value: likes
            };
            callback(null, data);
        });
    }).on('error', function(err) {
        callback(err, null);
    });
};

module.exports = getLikes;
```

I would like to test it with mocha AND sinon, but I don't get how to stub the `http.get`.

For now I'm doing a real `http.get` to facebook, but I would like to avoid it.

Here is my current test:

```
'use strict';
/*jshint expr: true*/
var should = require('chai').should(),
    getLikes = require('getLikes');

describe('getLikes', function() {

    it('shoud return likes', function(done) {
        getLikes(function(err, likes) {
            should.not.exist(err);
            likes._id.should.equal('likes');
            likes.value.should.exist();
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

How can I achieve what I want, without relying on something else than sinon? (I don't want to use the request module to perform the get, or using another testing lib)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with just `sinon.stub(http, 'get').yields(fakeStream);` but you might be better served by looking at [nock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock) and/or [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire). `nock` would let you fake the facebook response without mucking too much in the `getLikes` implementation details. `rewire` would let you swap in a mock `http` variable into the `getLikes` scope without monkey patching the `http.get` function globally.

Do do it with just sinon as above, you'll need to create a mock response that will properly resemble the stream. Something like:

```
var fakeLikes = {_id: 'likes', value: 'foo'};
var resumer = require('resumer');
var stream = resumer().queue(JSON.stringify(fakeLikes)).end()
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but mocha tells me done() is called twice, and I don't get it.

Comment: but when I put the stub in a before, I got a `TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined`. This is driving me nuts.